# SNAT source ip within same server

Tags: linux, networking, debian, iptables

What I am trying to do is to mask the client IPs when connecting to a UDP service using my virtual IP as a transparent proxy as showed below:

[client] -> [transparent proxy IP] [DNAT] ->[SNAT]-> [UDP service]

iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -d [transparent proxy IP] -m udp -p udp --sport [UDP service port] -j SNAT --to [UDP service IP]

This setup works if the transparent proxy and the UDP service are on 2 separate servers. However when I consolidated the servers into 1 server where the IPs of the transparent proxy and UDP service are attached as virtual interfaces, the SNAT fails and the UDP service sees the client IP.

How can I mimic the same effect? Am I looking at the wrong process flow and instead should be configuring on the loopback chain(this doesn't seem right to me as the traffic still goes out externally right)?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to use the INPUT chain of the NAT table:

```
iptables -t nat -I INPUT -p udp -m udp -d [UDP service IP] --dport [UDP service port] -j SNAT --to-source [transparent proxy IP]
```